# Java execuetorService running too fast?

Tags: groovy, executorservice

**By the following code**

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1*1000)
                        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing item " + i)
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

**I am expecting the output as follows:**

Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 1

Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 2

Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 3

Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 4

Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 5

Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 7

Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 6

Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 8

Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 9

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 0

**But it turns out to be:**

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 10

Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 10

The correct out put is by adding a temp variable before the executorService.exeute method. Here comes the question, what's the cause of the unexpected output?

Comment: Does that code actually compile? `i` isn't effectively final, so I would have thought the compiler would complain.

Comment: How did you get this to compile and run? This code should not compile, because the variable `i` needs to be effectively final in the anonymous inner class. (And you also forgot some semi-colons).

Comment: Post real code. The code above doesn't compile **at all**, it's not Java. (no semicolons at end of line, trying to use a non-final local variable in a method-local class, code not in a method and class, etc.)

Comment: As people have already mentioned, you should change your tags from java to the language you are using. Otherwise your question will likely be closed.

Comment: I added `;` at some places and made `i` static to compile your code. Tasks are submitted to `ExecutorService` and are executed at discretion of JVM. Value of `i` gets changed to 10 by the time tasks are executed. This is not always true, you can expect output to be 1,2,3 etc...

Comment: Actually I am using Groovy, sorry for the mix ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first off your code won't compile (at least not in Java, probably will do so in Groovy)
- 'i' cannot be used inside the block because it's not final and it cannot be final because it's used in the for-loop.

What do you mean by *"The correct out put is by adding a temp variable before the executorService.exeute method."* ?

Also, you shouldn't be expecting that output. You're not guaranteed an order like that, for example I got:

`Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 0
Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 1
Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 2
Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 5
Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 3
Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 4
Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 7
Thread pool-1-thread-2 processing item 8
Thread pool-1-thread-3 processing item 6
Thread pool-1-thread-1 processing item 9`

by using this code:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                    System.out.println("Thread "
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " processing item " + j);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and a `executorService.shutdown();` at the end

Comment: I am using Groovy, when switched to Java, the IDE shows me the warning message i should be final clearly  T_T

Answer (score 0):

All your runnables share the same instance of `i`.

By the time they run, this variable has a value of `10`

Hence the output.

If you use a closure, each runnable will get a new instance of `i` and you'll get the expected output:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)
10.times { i ->
   executorService.execute { ->
       Thread.sleep(1000)
       println "Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getName()} processing item $i"
   }
}
executorService.shutdown()
```

But they won't be in the order you say you expect, because threads...

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems that closure is a better choice in this case :)